# what is difference between logoff and shutdown?

Tags: windows-xp

i have a doubt what is difference between logoff and shudown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you log off, your session is ended, i.e. any programs you were running and your desktop, etc. and you return to the welcome screen. The PC still on, and there are system-level applications and services running.

When you shut down, everything stops running and the PC is powered off.

Comment: Nice explanation Mr. Graeme Donaldson  thank you for response

Answer (score 1):

Log off will log out of your session, but the computer will remain running. You have the option to log in under another user.

Shutdown will logout and turn the computer off :)

Comment: if my system is single user then there is no concept of logoff am i right? Mr. JT WK

Comment: no, you are not right.

Comment: why Mr.Akira. it is my doubt can u explain me thank you for response

Comment: Because Windows XP is always multi-user, even if you only use one user.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it? When you logoff, you logoff the current user and return to the login-screen. When you shutdown, you shutdown the computer wich then will be switched off.